# Same controller but conditional layouts in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a dashboard/posts and a frontpage/posts that both use the same 'posts' controller model.

I basically want all the actions available for both dashboard and frontpage except with different layouts.

Whats the best practice for my situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would create two new controllers that inherit from that 'posts' controller that you are using right now. Then just override the layout method in those new controllers.

If you can't do that, `layout` also takes a symbol instead of a string.

i.e. add `layout :dashboard_or_frontpage` to that controller. By specifying a symbol instead of a string, Rails will call the method with that name, expecting a string to be returned defining what layout to use: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Layouts/ClassMethods/layout

Without knowing a bit more about your setup, I can't help you with the logic needed to decide what layout to show. But it might look something like this.

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  layout :dashboard_or_frontpage

  private

  def dashboard_or_front_page
    if on_the_dashboard?
      "dashboard"
    else
      "front_page"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: The extends option is exactly what I was looking for! I have them both in a namespace(front::posts and dash::posts),  I'll create a non-namespaced parent controller (posts) they  both extend from. Awesome, thanks!

Comment: Good luck! Just to nitpick, I think the right terminology is inherit in the ruby world. Extend is used to refer to 'adding' class methods of a module to a target class: http://tianhsky.ueuo.com/blog/2012/03/18/ruby-class-inheritances-vs-extend-vs-include/

And in Rails we primarily inherit controllers from increasingly more general controllers, all the way down to ApplicationController which then itself inherits from ActionController::Base.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at this post http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html, you can use a :layout param with the render method.